# Hibernate @ManyToMany dudas

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

soy bastante novato en cuanto a Hibernate se refiere, el caso es que mirando documentacion de la anotacion `@ManyToMany` me ha surgido una duda, que se adecua bastante a mi caso, y es la siguiente:

Pongamos el caso que estoy desarrollando un juego y tengo las tablas characters y la tabla spells, es de logica que un character puede utilizar mas de un spell, por ejemplo "puñetazo" y "patada". Y que un mismo spell puede ser utilizado por varios characters diferentes.

El codigo de characters seria el siguiente:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "characterSpells", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "characterId") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "spellId") }
    )
    List<Spell> spells = new ArrayList<>();
```

Y el de spells el siguiente:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "spell")
    private List<Character> characters;
```

La cosa es que simplemente no me interesaria guardar en cada spell la lista de characters que lo usan.

Lo que pienso es si realmente esta relacion es `@ManyToMany` o `@OneToMany` donde @One es Spell y @Many es Characters, o simplemente estoy haciendo algo mal, o he entendido algo mal.

Comment: Si no te interesa simplemente no uses la relación, de hecho sería recomendable no hacer para evitar llamadas inecesarias a la bd, y dado que en characters la relación la haces con el joinTable y no directamente con el atributo de spells, simplemente no la pongas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esos campos son requeridos principalmente para generar las relaciones de entidades subyacentes en JPA, así JPA podrá realizar consultas y optimizaciones basándose en esas relaciones.

Sin embargo, como es tu caso, no siempre se va a requerir tener las referencias a las entidades con las cuales está relacionada cierta entidad.

Para eso existe un atributo de las anotaciones JPA que indican relaciones entre entidades/tablas (`@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`) llamado `fetch`, que permite especificar el modo en que JPA carga u obtiene de la base de datos las entidades relacionadas con una entidad.

### Carga (Fetching) de Entidades Relacionadas

Existen dos posibilidades:

***FetchType.LAZY* - Carga postergada (o perezosa)**

Carga todas las entidades relacionadas con una entidad en el momento en que se carga esa misma entidad, no importa que nunca las uses. Por ejemplo:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGE)
```

***FetchType.EAGER* - Carga temprana**

Carga las entidades relacionadas con una entidad SOLO cuando se necesiten, es decir, cuando hagas referencia a esa relación llamando a la lista. Por ejemplo:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

Cabe mencionar que el fetchType por defecto para las relaciones a-Uno (`@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne`) es EAGER y para las relaciones a-Muchos (`@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`) es LAZY.

**¿Por qué es importante?**
En una sola palabra: Rendimiento. Una carga temprana requerirá una consulta adicional a la base de datos por parte de JPA, lo que traduce en un retraso al cargar la entidad raíz. Por otro lado, una carga postergada, hará la carga de la entidad raíz más rápida, pero habrá un retraso al momento de usar las entidades relacionadas con esa entidad. Claro está, la duración de esos retrasos son casi siempre milisegundos o menos, todo depende de la cantidad de registros relacionados a la entidad raíz, quizás a partir de decenas de miles de registros se pueda percibir ese retraso.

---

Para darte una respuesta directa a tu pregunta.
Debes dejar las relaciones @ManyToMany.
Sin embargo, si no vas a necesitar obtener los caracteres que usan ese hechizo, déjale el FetchType en LAZY en la relación de la entidad `Character`. Aunque por defecto ya tiene `FetchType.LAZY`, así que lo puedes dejar tal y como está.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "characterSpells", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "characterId") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "spellId") }
    )
    List<Spell> spells = new ArrayList<>();
```

Y para la entidad `Spell` si debes especificarle cambiarle el FetchType a EAGER. (Supongo que requerirás saber desde el momento en que se crea el `Character` que `Spell`s puede usar).

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "spell", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Character> characters;
```